# constant independent of time, meaning of this line?

Tags: phasor

can someone please explain last paragraph in the Picture that i have uploaded, in layman's term specially this phrase "constant independent of time"

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- In the first case (where \$x_1(t)\$ and \$x_2(t)\$ are two sinusoidal signals that differ only in amplitude but not in frequency or phase angle) the quotient
  \$\frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)}\$ is a constant. I.e. the quotient is the same at any time.
- In the second case (where \$x_1(t)\$ and \$x_2(t)\$ are two sinusoidal signals that differ only in phase offset but not in amplitude or frequency) the quotient
  \$\frac{x_1(t)}{x_2(t)}\$ is a not constant. I.e. the quotient is a function of time; it changes over time. In general it is not equal at two different times.

The expressions "constant *independent of time*" means that only dependence with respect to time is considered here. In other cases it might be interesting to consider dependency of other quantities, e.g. of frequency or space.